# Is there any management API for Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I am looking to build a multi Chanel bot service in my application using Microsoft Bot Framework, I cant find out the documentation for managing creating bot app, adding and updating channels in bot. is it possible to do those activities programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. There is no API for that yet.

Comment: Microsoft replied in mail like this , It is not possible to create a bot and configure its channels programmatically. The best way to do this is by going into the dev portal (https://dev.botframework.com). :(

Comment: you can use the az bot command line. I don't know how to integrate this in a web app scenario written in dot.net.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is an API 
Microsoft Azure Management Bot Service Library 
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService -Version 0.9.1-preview

```
    public string RegisterFbChanelTest()
        {
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile("azureauth.json");
            var client = new AzureBotServiceClient(credentials){SubscriptionId = "xxxxx"};

            var fbChanel = new FacebookChannel();
            fbChanel.Properties = new FacebookChannelProperties()
            {
                AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                IsEnabled = true,
                Pages = new List<FacebookPage>()
                {
                    new FacebookPage()
                    {
                        Id ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        AccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                }
            };

            var chanel = new BotChannel(
                name: @"buttlerbot/FacebookChannel",
                type: "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels",
                location: "global",
                properties: fbChanel,
 type: "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels",

                );

            var chanels = client.Channels.ListByResourceGroup("bots", "xbuttlerbot");

            //  client.Channels.Delete("bots", "xbuttlerbot", "FacebookChannel");
            var result = client.Channels.Create("bots", "xbuttlerbot", Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService.Models.ChannelName.FacebookChannel,
             chanel
                 );
            return "";
        }
```

Make sure to check the bot Activity In Azure portal.

[image: AzurePortalBotActivity]