# Can we host Microsoft Bot Connector and Bot Framework on-premise?

Tags: botframework

We are trying to automate Bot App creation and channel registrations. Currently I don't find any API's I can use to make this all work from backend. Started exploring how to host the connector service and bot app registration on an on-premise server with internet access.

More interested in using Microsoft Bot Framework than other open source ones. Did anyone already solved this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any management API for Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183423/is-there-any-management-api-for-bot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment to automatically create bots and configure channels. You need to visit our dev portal (dev.botframework.com) to do so. There are no plans to add this feature that I am aware of.

Regards,
Francisco